# rails_env setting in NGINX not affecting Passenger

Tags: nginx, passenger

I've had a working ruby application installed on NGINX & Phusion/Passenger (ubuntu), and I upgraded the ruby version from version 1.9.2 to 1.9.3. After the upgrade the ruby application is using 'production' environment instead of 'development'. I verified the NGINX config file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

```
server {
  listen                        80;
  server_name                   localhost;
  root                          /home/myroot;
  passenger_enabled             on;
  rails_env                     development;
...
```

I have enabled passenger debug log, and in the passenger log I see:

```
I have control 1.0
You have control 1.0
passenger_root: /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini
ruby_libdir: /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
passenger_version: 4.0.50
generation_dir: /tmp/passenger.1.0.5644/generation-0
...
app_type: rack
start_command: /usr/local/rvm/bin/ruby-1.9.3-p484@reveal+--/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-loader.rb
startup_file: config.ru
process_title: Passenger RackApp
log_level: 3
start_timeout: 90000
environment: production
```

Why is the rails_env settings not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run Rails app using Phusion Passenger, by default, it runs in ‘production’ mode. However, if you want to run it in ‘development’ mode for any reason, you need to add a directive in your apache/nginx configuration.

**Nginx:**

```
rack_env development
```

You can put the above option in any of the following places:

- In the http configuration block.
- In a server configuration block.
- In a location configuration block.
- In an if configuration scope.